# Eclipse "Nothing to Build for Project" Error on Build

Tags: c, build, eclipse-cdt, build-error

I realize this has been asked before, on this site and others, but none have provided a satisfactory answer. I'm just starting out with C/C++ and I'm using the Eclipse CDT on Mac. After creating a C project, then creating a source file (with the proper .cpp suffix), and writing a simple "Hello World!" program, I get the following error in the console: "Nothing to build for project [name]". There is nothing wrong with the code, as far as I know.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with the gcc configuration or anything, although I am not entirely certain. The source file is saved and appears to be under the project, so I am not sure how to resolve this particular problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a project with `main` already included?  That should definitely work.

Comment: How do I include main? (Again, I am completely new to C and Eclipse)

Comment: Should be a option when you create a new project.

Comment: I'm not seeing any options in the new project window. The new project window just shows the options to select project type, toolchains, and configurations.

Answer (score 9):

The project would not build *because* it had the .cpp prefix, which implied a C++ file (in a C project). Everything worked when I changed it to .c.

Answer (score 1):

In case of make error,go to project ->properties->c/c++ build->tool chain editor->select tools and select Cygwin C Compiler for C and Cygwin C++ Compiler for C++